# creating jscrollpane-arrows outsite jspContainer

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

Is there an easy way to create the arrows outside the jspcontainter and horizontally arranged for a vertical scroll bar? As the container has overflow:hidden with positioning the arrows cannot be displayed outside.

I tried to clone the arrows with jquery clonefunction, but the js hangs up scrolling up again. Is there a way to add default-behavior to custom controls outside the container with the api?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be to not show arrows on the jScrollPane itself and then create different elements outside and position them as you like. You could then add a click handler to these new elements and in it use the [jScrollPane API](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html) and the [scrollByY](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html#scrollByY) method to make the jscrollpane scroll when they are clicked on...