# Assigning new Arrows divs for jquery scroll pane

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I'm customizing a UI scrolling window, that scrolls horizontally filled with pictures.  I've applied the jquery `scroll-pane` to the container `div` and it succesfully applied the customer scrollbars.  it was as simple as this... and adding the `main-scroll-pane` class to the described window.

```
$(function()
{
    $('.main-scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
```

What i'm trying to do is redefine the arrow divs to arrows that reside outside the container div, on either side...

Is there any sort of script I could implement to get

```
$(function(){$('.main-scroll-pane-left-arrow').jScrollPane();});
```

functional on a `div class=".scroll-pane-left-arrow"`

I've read into the API a little and this is allowed :
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html

Does anyone know any ways to clarify exactly how I should implement this and what sort of script is required to extend the plugin to have this sort of functionality for more than just one scroll pane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was prettymuch asked and answered here:
[creating jscrollpane-arrows outsite jspContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388842/creating-jscrollpane-arrows-outsite-jspcontainer)

But to elaborate on my answer from then, here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/WzNM4/6/

You need to add listeners for the links and then use the [jScrollPane API](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html) to tell the jScrollPane to scroll:

```
$(function()
{
    var api = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
    $('#scroll-up').bind(
        'mousedown',
        function()
        {
            var interval = setInterval(
                function()
                {
                    api.scrollByY(-5);
                },
                100
            );
            $(window).bind(
                'mouseup.jspExample',
                function()
                {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    $(document).unbind('.jspExample');
                }
            );
        }
    );
    $('#scroll-down').bind(
        'mousedown',
        function()
        {
            var interval = setInterval(
                function()
                {
                    api.scrollByY(5);
                },
                100
            );
            $(window).bind(
                'mouseup.jspExample',
                function()
                {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    $(document).unbind('.jspExample');
                }
            );
        }
    );
});
```

Note that the code is complicated a bit because I wanted to show how you can make the scroll continue happening while the mouse button is held down (hence the need for setInterval and an additional listener for mouseup). The code could also be simplified so both buttons shared an event handler but I think it is more understandable (although longer) in this form...

Answer (score 1):

built on the above version here is an horizontal alternative http://jsfiddle.net/WzNM4/119/